# Android Project - R cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, r.java-file

I've been working on an android project, but a really annoying error is killing me: "R cannot be resolved or is not a field". Well, there's many questions who got answers, but everything I tried for now doesn't work: clean project, destroy R.java & clean project, import x.y.z.R; and destroy any import android.R;... but it's still there. Will you be able to help me?

Here comes the code where the error occurs (ListArretsActivity.java):

```
package com.example.onetantan;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.onetantan.rest.Arret;
import com.example.onetantan.rest.ArretRestMethod;
import com.example.onetantan.rest.ListArret;
import com.example.onetantan.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class ListArretsActivity extends ListActivity {
    ... // Code that doesn't seemed revelant, for me, for the error given
        class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... paramArrayOfParams) {
                ArretRestMethod arm = new ArretRestMethod(ListArretsActivity.this.R);
                return null;
            }
        }
    ... // Code that doesn't seemed revelant, for me, for the error given
}
```

Here comes a code where there's no problem... (ArretAdapter.java):

```
package com.example.onetantan;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.onetantan.rest.Arret;
import com.example.onetantan.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ArretAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static String LOG_TAG="ArretAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Arret> mListArret;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ArretAdapter(Context p_oContext, List<Arret> p_oListArret){
        super();
        mContext = p_oContext;
        mListArret = p_oListArret;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }
    ... // Code that doesn't seemed revelant, for me, for the error given
    @Override
    public View getView(int p_iPosition, View p_oConvertView, ViewGroup p_oParentView) {
        if (p_oConvertView == null) {
            p_oConvertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arret_item, null);
        }
        ((TextView)(p_oConvertView.findViewById(R.id.name))).setText("Heure");
        ((TextView)(p_oConvertView.findViewById(R.id.dist))).setText("Heure");
        return p_oConvertView;
    }
    ... // Code that doesn't seemed revelant, for me, for the error given
}
```

And for finishing, a picture of my package explorer for src & gen folders. Wanted to post an image, but doesn't have enough reputation since I'm a new user, so here goes a link : http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/5511/tosend.png

It's been a week since I haven't been able to do a thing... maybe is something too obvious that I don't see, or a serious problem, but I really need your help.

Thanks in advance for any answers you can give me (even if it's answers from other problems that I've tried three times, I'll try again if needed).

EDIT: One of your answers was to check my xml files for any error. But Eclipse doesn't send back any error and I don't see any (I'm not experimented at all... :/ ).
In my res>layout folder: arret_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my res>layout folder: arret_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListArretsActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

These are the only two .xml files in my res.layout that I may be edited.

EDIT 2: Running Android Lint, it only returns me warnings:

Not targeting the latest versions of Android; comptability modes apply.
.gif format for bitmaps is discouraged (64 items)
Found bitmap drawable res/drawable/l_1.gif in densityless folder (68 items)
The ressource R.drawable.l_1 appears to be unused (70 items)

I corrected right away the first one since I'm working on API 17 (Android 4.2), and my manifest was on 16. But it doesn't correct my error.

For the 3 other warnings, it's normal since I don't use them for the moment an I was given the project with these.

Well, here comes my AndroidManifest.xml since I edited it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.onetantan"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.onetantan.ListArretsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer: Sorry everyone, there's a code I haven't given and it's ArretRestMethod.java. If I've given you this one, you'll maybe understand:

```
package com.example.onetantan.rest;

import ...

public class ArretRestMethod {
        private static String LOG_TAG="ArretRestMethod";
        Context mContext=null;

        public ArretRestMethod(Context context) {
            mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        }
        ...
}
```

One of my friends pointed me out for the line in ListArretsActivity.java

```
ArretRestMethod arm = new ArretRestMethod(ListArretsActivity.this.R);
```

must be written like this:

```
ArretRestMethod arm = new ArretRestMethod(ListArretsActivity.this);
```

Free whips will be given to anyone who want to give me a punishment... :x (I'm ashamed that I didn't saw this... sorry everyone. But I have learned at least some things by asking there.)

Comment: You shouldnt be importing import com.example.onetantan.R;

Comment: Is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at top of arret_item.xml? that's necessary if t isn't and may break your _R_ references.

Comment: Try change your **API** to another level after that turn back to original one. And check **ErrorLog** or **Problem** view incase there some error.

Comment: Please stop changing the tag to [r].  Read the tag info for [the r tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) and [the r.java-file tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r.java-file/info).

Comment: Oh my bad, I'll try to be carefull about that next time. :x

Answer (score 1):

ust clean your project ....

```
in eclipse goto -->projects --> select clean --> select your project ( shows in popup )
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work.
It's the answer that I've seen the most, and I've done that like more than 20 times, but it doesn't make it work better. Anyway, tried again but no, my project is still stubborn. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try cleaning and restarting Eclipse. Sadly restarting Eclipse is needed sometimes.

Comment: Restarting Eclipse didn't helped either (I do it like every hour). And for the error log, if you mean the Problems View, only this one is given, and a lot of warnings concerning .gif images not used for the moment and unused imports that I'll remove right away.

Answer (score 1):

- check your recently edited xml files for errors. Eclipse sometimes misses errors in the xml files so you might have to open the files you edited recently.
- check if any of the
  resources in your res folder have illegal characters in the filename.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't send back any error... and I doesn't see any. I'll edit my post for giving my xml codes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is at top of arret_item.xml. It's missing from the code you posted, but my be just a copy-paste omission. That's necessary if it isn't there and may break your R references.

Also, try running `Android Lint` in Eclipse. It will help point to warnings that may actually be errors that aren't reported.

Lint details: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint#TOC-Eclipse-Usage

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advise, didn't know about Android Lint. But it only returned me warnings. Otherwise, the missing first line in arret_item.xml was a copy-paste omission.

Comment: Try to fix the warnings if you can. They may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArretRestMethod arm = new ArretRestMethod(ListArretsActivity.this.R);
```

Why do you need R in the above line? I believe it requires  a context instance.

If so,
make a field - `Context context;`
in onCreate - `context= this;`
use context as - `ArretRestMethod arm = new ArretRestMethod(context);`

If some other parameter is required pass that instead.

Answer (score 0):

IF ALL ELSE FAILS... **create a new project and manually copy all of your files over.**

I was recently performing an update on code that hadn't been touched in 15 months and couldn't get past this. There's probably a config setting I missed or some other trivial piece, but I'm wishing I had just done this 3 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After much struggling with Clean, Restarts and other first hand attemps, I deleted:

import android.R;

and replaced it with my package's name

import com.josh.microqr

Seems dumb but after many Cleans, little mistakes like this one drag on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is nothing wrong with your xml and other setting then first take backup of your project and delete your R file in "gen" folder now Build project again this will regenerate your R file(this will work only if your project don't have error other then "R cannot be resolved or is not a field").

Answer (score 0):

I think any of below should help you resolve this problem:

- Check you xml files for errors.
- Check if your res folder has files which has invalid character in file name
- Do project->clean project. It will regenerate the R.java file.

RK 
http://ctrlaltsolve.blogspot.in